# Render json response in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and Java.
I trying to make an API call and then render it in Kotlin.

This is how I get the JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "AWBNo": "1326217373504",
    "AuthKey": "Valid",
    "OrderNo": "SGHRGR15073TCC",
    "ReturnMessage": "Successful",
    "ShipmentSummary": [
      {
        "PickUpDate": "08-10-2017",
        "PickUpTime": "0015",
        "OriginLocation": "DEL/WDL, Delhi NCR, DELHI",
        "DestinationLocation": "",
        "Weight": "0",
        "ExpectedDeliveryDate": "10/11/2017 12:21:32 AM",
        "Status": "Delivered",
        "StatusCode": "DLVD",
        "StatusDate": "11-10-2017",
        "StatusTime": "1316",
        "Location": "Berhampur, Berhampur, ORISSA",
        "Comment": "Shipment Delivered by SR: RAKESH, DeliveryDate:2017-10-11 1316, Receiver Name: Manmandir  Mobile Accessories  Remarks : "
      },
      {
        "PickUpDate": "08-10-2017",
        "PickUpTime": "0015",
        "OriginLocation": "DEL/WDL, Delhi NCR, DELHI",
        "DestinationLocation": "",
        "Weight": "0",
        "ExpectedDeliveryDate": "10/11/2017 12:21:32 AM",
        "Status": "Out for Delivery",
        "StatusCode": "OFD",
        "StatusDate": "11-10-2017",
        "StatusTime": "0858",
        "Location": "Berhampur, Berhampur, ORISSA",
        "Comment": "Out for delivery: 39031-RAKESH-PDS1728408582139031"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

how can I use this to be rendered in a java object.

I understand we need to create a POJO data class similar to the response we receive.

would be grateful if you can show me a sample class which will work with this.

Comment: You can create Kotlin POJO at https://json2kotlin.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample class code gives you a **GSON** library annotation class code. Which you can use to parse your json.

You can simple remove annotation if you want to use normal class in Kotlin and java.

You can use below Kotlin class to parse your json response:

**Kotlin class code:** :

Link: https://pastebin.com/gXq3TrXf

```
 class Example {
  @SerializedName("AWBNo")
  @Expose
  var awbNo:String
  @SerializedName("AuthKey")
  @Expose
  var authKey:String
  @SerializedName("OrderNo")
  @Expose
  var orderNo:String
  @SerializedName("ReturnMessage")
  @Expose
  var returnMessage:String
  @SerializedName("ShipmentSummary")
  @Expose
  var shipmentSummary:List<ShipmentSummary> = null
  inner class ShipmentSummary {
    @SerializedName("PickUpDate")
    @Expose
    var pickUpDate:String
    @SerializedName("PickUpTime")
    @Expose
    var pickUpTime:String
    @SerializedName("OriginLocation")
    @Expose
    var originLocation:String
    @SerializedName("DestinationLocation")
    @Expose
    var destinationLocation:String
    @SerializedName("Weight")
    @Expose
    var weight:String
    @SerializedName("ExpectedDeliveryDate")
    @Expose
    var expectedDeliveryDate:String
    @SerializedName("Status")
    @Expose
    var status:String
    @SerializedName("StatusCode")
    @Expose
    var statusCode:String
    @SerializedName("StatusDate")
    @Expose
    var statusDate:String
    @SerializedName("StatusTime")
    @Expose
    var statusTime:String
    @SerializedName("Location")
    @Expose
    var location:String
    @SerializedName("Comment")
    @Expose
    var comment:String
  }
}
```

**Java class Code:**

Link: https://pastebin.com/zrPNB0T4

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("AWBNo")
@Expose
private String aWBNo;
@SerializedName("AuthKey")
@Expose
private String authKey;
@SerializedName("OrderNo")
@Expose
private String orderNo;
@SerializedName("ReturnMessage")
@Expose
private String returnMessage;
@SerializedName("ShipmentSummary")
@Expose
private List<ShipmentSummary> shipmentSummary = null;

public String getAWBNo() {
return aWBNo;
}

public void setAWBNo(String aWBNo) {
this.aWBNo = aWBNo;
}

public String getAuthKey() {
return authKey;
}

public void setAuthKey(String authKey) {
this.authKey = authKey;
}

public String getOrderNo() {
return orderNo;
}

public void setOrderNo(String orderNo) {
this.orderNo = orderNo;
}

public String getReturnMessage() {
return returnMessage;
}

public void setReturnMessage(String returnMessage) {
this.returnMessage = returnMessage;
}

public List<ShipmentSummary> getShipmentSummary() {
return shipmentSummary;
}

public void setShipmentSummary(List<ShipmentSummary> shipmentSummary) {
this.shipmentSummary = shipmentSummary;
}


public class ShipmentSummary {

@SerializedName("PickUpDate")
@Expose
private String pickUpDate;
@SerializedName("PickUpTime")
@Expose
private String pickUpTime;
@SerializedName("OriginLocation")
@Expose
private String originLocation;
@SerializedName("DestinationLocation")
@Expose
private String destinationLocation;
@SerializedName("Weight")
@Expose
private String weight;
@SerializedName("ExpectedDeliveryDate")
@Expose
private String expectedDeliveryDate;
@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("StatusCode")
@Expose
private String statusCode;
@SerializedName("StatusDate")
@Expose
private String statusDate;
@SerializedName("StatusTime")
@Expose
private String statusTime;
@SerializedName("Location")
@Expose
private String location;
@SerializedName("Comment")
@Expose
private String comment;

public String getPickUpDate() {
return pickUpDate;
}

public void setPickUpDate(String pickUpDate) {
this.pickUpDate = pickUpDate;
}

public String getPickUpTime() {
return pickUpTime;
}

public void setPickUpTime(String pickUpTime) {
this.pickUpTime = pickUpTime;
}

public String getOriginLocation() {
return originLocation;
}

public void setOriginLocation(String originLocation) {
this.originLocation = originLocation;
}

public String getDestinationLocation() {
return destinationLocation;
}

public void setDestinationLocation(String destinationLocation) {
this.destinationLocation = destinationLocation;
}

public String getWeight() {
return weight;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
this.weight = weight;
}

public String getExpectedDeliveryDate() {
return expectedDeliveryDate;
}

public void setExpectedDeliveryDate(String expectedDeliveryDate) {
this.expectedDeliveryDate = expectedDeliveryDate;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getStatusCode() {
return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getStatusDate() {
return statusDate;
}

public void setStatusDate(String statusDate) {
this.statusDate = statusDate;
}

public String getStatusTime() {
return statusTime;
}

public void setStatusTime(String statusTime) {
this.statusTime = statusTime;
}

public String getLocation() {
return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
this.location = location;
}

public String getComment() {
return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
this.comment = comment;
}

}

}
```

You can use your class name by replacing `Example`.